# Build warning for distribution configuration of an iPad only application

Tags: iphone, ipad, build, dependencies, warnings

I'm getting the following warning when building an ad hoc distribution copy of a new iPad only application:

```
[BWARN]warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' that includes iPad ('2') requires building with the 3.2 or later SDK.
```

These are my build settings:

**Architectures:** Optimized (armv6 armv7)
**Any iPhone OS Simulator:** i386
**Any iPhone OS Device:** Optimized (armv6 armv7)
**Base SDK:** iPhone Device 3.2
**Valid Architectures:** armv6 armv7
**Target Device Family:** iPad
**iPhone OS Deployment Target:** iPhone OS 3.2

With this in mind I don't understand the warning. It seems to build and run OK but I'd rather not have warnings in my build for obvious reasons.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Alan.

Comment: OK. I think it's related to the additional SDK I've added for JSON parsing. I've seen some other posts mentioning having an additional SDK defined causing confusion. I'll see what options I have for getting around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the problem was the additional SDK I'd added for JSON parsing. Was working fine until I started trying to build for iPad only in 3.2.
I removed the additional SDK and linker information, pulled in the source files instead and am now able to build without any issues.